# jQuery Set Lookup Column Value

Tags: jquery, lookup-column

When using jQuery, what is the syntax to set a lookup column to a value retrieved from another lookup column.  I have been able to prepopulate a string column with a value retrieved from a lookup column, but am having trouble setting a lookup column to this value.  How do I set the lookup column to the id of the value that the jQuery retrieved for me?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you explain a little more? How are your lookup columns related?

If you take a look at my [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) jQuery library, it may give you some clues. The way I read your question, you should probably just be setting to the text value, not bothering with the ID.

Comment: Hi Marc.  Thank you for your response.  The lookup columns are not related to each other, they are the same.  I am trying to take the Divison that a particular employee belongs to (Stored in the User Information List) and prepopulate another Division lookup field on the NewForm.aspx with the same value.  This value could be changed if necessary.  I haven't been able to get it to work with the lookup column.  I'm not trying to change the datasource in the lookup, just pre-select the value.  It will put the correct value in a textbox, however.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Same answer as in your other post, I think: take a look at SPServices!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
 var selector="select[title=MyLookup]"; $(selector).val(newValue);
```

the newValue could be an ordinal of the option or the displayed text equivalent of the option.

HTH

Comment: Disclaimer: This is oversimplified as lookup UI renders and behaves differently for under-20- and more-than-20-options-lookups. Read Marc's blog or EUSP for more details.

Comment: Thank you AKrasheninnikov. It works fine when I use the ordinal of the option, however, I am not able to make it work with the text equivalent. I tried to hardcode the text equivalent as well. Do you know what I doing wrong?  Thank you.

Comment: In my case it works like this $("td.ms-formbody select[title=Delivery status]").val("Shipped"), even when the actual "Delivery status" and "Shipped" are UTF-8 extended symbols. Make sure the value is exactly equal to the contents of the corresponding <option>option</option>